# Can not apply jquery for element loaded by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click Button 2, Nothing happen. How do it run like I writed. My code:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1"><br><br>
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn1").click(function(){
           $("#display").append('<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button 2">');
       }); 
       $("#btn2").click(function(){
           alert("Message!");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation on dynamically created elements, like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn2", function(){
    alert("Message!");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/4hx2mtso/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation to add event listeners to dynamically created elements.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn1").click(function(){
           $("#display").append('<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button 2">');
       }); 
       $(document).on('click','#btn2',function(){ // document or any container of btn2
           alert("Message!");
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1"><br><br>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: If my code is:

       $(document).on('click','a',function(){ 
           $("body").remove(?);
       });

I want current a tag which I selected will be remove. How do I do?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','a',function(){ $(this).remove(); });` beware by `a` you are selecting all `a`s. You should use some class or id instead.